# Migration from .NET to angular2: How to redirect old (absolute) links?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Simply put, we want to have our old links redirect to our new routes.  I know how to do this with app-routes.ts, however, it doesn't *exactly* work.  Example:

`export const ROUTES: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'my-loads',
        component: MyLoadsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'Applications/LoadBoard/CarrierBoard.aspx',
        redirectTo: 'my-loads'
      }
    ]`

This redirect actually works, but only if the user tries to visit `/#/Applications/MyApp/Controller.aspx` (with hash), but will NOT work if the user tries to visit `/Applications/MyApp/Controller.aspx` (without hash, which is the URL users will have bookmarked).

This is because webpack/angular2 apparently uses **relative** URLs to load ALL of the scripts required to use the site.  It's trying to load `script.bundle.js` instead of `/script.bundle.js`, so it turns out to try to load `/Applications/MyApp/script.bundle.js`. This being the case, if you try to visit an absolute URL other than root, all you get is 404s for the required scripts, so none of the scripts run, and you're presented with "Loading..." and nothing else.

I get that the idea for that sort of compilation is to allow users to build webapps that do NOT reside in the root folder.  This is a good idea, but it is preventing us from redirecting old URLs.  Is there a (correct) way of implementing these redirects within angular2?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `<base href="/">` to the HTML `<head>` tag fixes the issue regarding angular trying to load scripts from the wrong path.

To get the route redirecting correctly, we have to remove hashes from our routes in our `app.module.ts`, changing the RouterModule line to

```
(RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: false })
```

Comment: I am still researching how to have the base HREF be environment dependent, instead of hard-coded. Luckily, the base href should be / on each developer's environment, as well as staging and prod, but I'd still like this to be an environment variable.